# What is the meaning of the DocuSign attribute ApplyAnchorTabs

Tags: docusignapi

I'm using DocuSign REST API v.2 and I've seen that for each document to be signed there is the attribute ApplyAnchorTabs, but I haven't found informations about its use; I have set it both 'true' and 'false' but the result is always the same.
What is the meaning of ApplyAnchorTabs ?
Thanks

Comment: where do you see this? are you using the native ios SDK?

Comment: I'm using DocuSign Java library for REST API

Answer (score 0):

When you add a new document to an envelope, you can decide if you want your pre-defined anchor-tabs to be applied to it. So You could have an envelope with multiple documents and only some of them use the anchor tabs.
Anchor tabs are strings that are used to determine where tabs (signing elements) are positions. So you can position them either using X/Y coordinates or using strings that you find in the document to help you place them.

Answer (score 0):

The property is listed as TBD, reserved.

https://docusign.github.io/docusign-esign-csharp-client/class_docu_sign_1_1e_sign_1_1_model_1_1_document.html#a00682f3e472d9057a741661e47049370

[Docusign Reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/STqbV.png)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34892697)